# Properly Positioning SMD Headers KiCAD

Tags: surface-mount, kicad

I'm currently working on a PCB in KiCAD and am using some SMD header pins. In a previous design I used THT headers and it was super easy to measure from center to center of the holes to make sure the Arduino I'm using will fit on the board. Now that I'm using surface mount headers, I can't actually see where the female sockets will be on the headers and don't want any rude awakenings when my PCB comes back from fab.

Does anyone have any tips on how to properly space these out to ensure the headers will be dimensioned correctly? I measured from center of pad to pad, but am not confident that will be the correct spacing. I might just have to do some math: here's the datasheet for the headers I'm using: https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/571/Catalog-1063651.pdf

[image: Through Hole]

[image: Surface Mount]

Thanks!

**I ended up figuring out a decent enough solution. If anyone else is curious on how to do something similar, I ended up editing the footprint. The origin of the footprint was at the center of the header socket, so I placed a circular pad with its center in the middle of the rectangular pad and then am able to measure from the center of that with the trace tool.**

Comment: Did you intend to shift the SMT placement to the right  relative to vias?  Looks like some traces have to be re-routed

Comment: Ya that was intentional, I'm reworking quite a bit. I looked into the footprint for my headers and it looks like the reference origin is at the center of the socket. I added a graphic circle at the center of the pad, but am still not sure how to measure from center of that.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. It is symmetrical.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqHBk.png

Comment: Print out the GERBER 1:1, stick the headers into the Arduino and place it on the paper. Though the pins are centered on the footprint anyways so you theoretically shouldn't need to do that.

Comment: Maybe the pads crossing over the center line is confusing?